# Simple MySql SELECT

Tags: mysql

I have a table that assigns workdays to worker-IDs.

```
Table: workdays       Table: jobs
+------+-------+      +------+-----------+
| id   | days  |      | id   | jobs      |
+------+-------+      +------+-----------+
|    1 |  mon  |      |    1 | cleaning  |
|    1 |  tue  |      |    2 | cooking   |
|    2 |  sat  |      |    3 | driving   |
|    3 |  mon  |      |    4 | cleaning  |
|    3 |  tue  |      |    5 | cooking   |
|    3 |  sat  |      +------+-----------+
|    4 |  wed  |
|    4 |  mon  |
|    5 |  tue  |
+------+-------+
```

This is the query I use to select the IDs of people who work on any of the days I specify (say Monday and Tuesday):

```
SELECT * FROM workdays WHERE days IN ( 'mon', 'tue' )
```

Now I'd like to select those people who work on ALL of the days I specify. How can I do that?

edit: Added second table.

Comment: Assuming (id,days) is UNIQUE... GROUP BY id HAVING COUNT(*) = number of items in IN()

Comment: @Zap7 Nope. It will return **empty**.

Comment: @今草顿웃 yup... wasn't thinking :)

Comment: I wonder if the OP is expecting to return the people that work in ALL of those days and ONLY in those days

Answer (score 4, accepted):

assuming `days` is unique for every `id`.

```
SELECT id
FROM workdays 
WHERE days IN ('mon', 'tue')
GROUP BY id
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
```

otherwise, you need to have `DISTINCT` in `HAVING` clause to count only unique values.

```
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT days) = 2
```

Comment: Great, thank you! One more thing: Let's say I have another table assigning a jobs to every worker. How could I select all workers available on monday and tuesday AND doing the cleaning for example? I tried "SELECT * FROM workdays NATURAL LEFT JOIN jobs WHERE days IN ('mon, 'tue') AND job IN ('cleaning')", but it doesn't return any results.

Comment: I added it to my post.